# How to map an image and link it to another image?

Tags: html

Usually, I always map image to link to another website, or link to a text within a page.

Now, I have 2 images within a page. I would like to link image A to image B.

Example, when I click specific part in image A (using `<map>` & `<area>` for specific part), it will link to specific part of image B.

Image B is quite long in height, but I want to link specific part in image B

```
<img src="imageA.png" usemap="#imageA"/>
<img src="imageB.png" usemap="#imageB"/>

<map name="imageA"> 
<area href="#linkImageAtoB" shape="rect" coords="659,558,825,588" alt="Test"/>
</map> 

<map name="imageB"> 
<a name="linkImageAtoB"><area shape="rect" coords="17,92,343,135" alt="Test"/></a>
</map>
```

Comment: post some code that you have tried to help you better.

Comment: sorry about that. I have already posted

Answer (score 1):

Use image map

```html
    <img src="image1" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#imagemap">

    <map name="imagemap">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,145,126"  href="image2.htm">
  
    </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use links around images the same way like around text. With `href="#..."` you can link to a certain ID within your page.

So for your case, something like this should make it:

```
<a href="#B">
    <img id="A" src="..." />
</a>
<a href="#A">
    <img id="B" src="..." />
</a>
```

Comment: I'm making use of <map> & <area> .. I have already posted my code